# Understanding the php pipeline when using nginx and php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php

So I'm trying to understand how the PHP pipeline works from request to response, specifically when using nginx and php-fpm.

I'm coming from a java/.net background so normally once the process is sent the request it uses threads etc. to handle the request/response cycle.

With php/nginx, I noticed the fpm process is setup like:

```
location / {
    include /path/to/php-fpm;
}
```

Here are a few questions I have:

1. when nginx recieves request, does php-fpm take over, if so, at what point?
2. does each request spawn another process/thread?
3. when you make a change to a php source code file, do you have to reload?  If not, does this mean each time a request comes in it parses the source code each time?

Any other interesting points about how a php request is served that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You configuration in your post is irrelevant as `include /path/to/php-fpm;` is the inclusion of an nginx configuration subpart.

1. It doens't take over anything, the request is passed from nginx to php-fpm with fastcgi_pass and nginx waits for the reply to come back but serve other request in the meantime.
2. Nginx uses the reactor pattern so requests are served by a limited amount of processes (usually the amount is the same than the amount of CPU cores available on the machine). It's an event driven web server that uses event polling to treat many requests on each process (asynchronous). In the other side php fpm uses a process pool to execute php code.
3. No you don't, because there's no caching anywhere unless you setup browser client's caching headers or server cache. It doesn't parse the php source code each time if the file is unchanged and frequently accessed because of OS caching. When the file content changes then yes it will be parsed again, as a normal file would be.